# Alternative to Intra-class correlation coefficient (ICC) for continuous data

Tags: correlation, reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I am working on a research project that involves a reliability study. In this case, 3 raters have assigned two sets of scores to 50 items: an ordinal score on a scale from 1 - 3, and a continuous score on a scale from 0 - 100.

I have used the intra-class correlation coefficient (ICC) to measure the inter-rater reliability for the ordinal as well as the continuous score, however have received feedback that a 'parametric testing measure' should be used instead for the continuous outcome.

Might you be able to point me to the most appropriate / commonly used measure for this purpose?

Comment: ICC is parametric. You should ask whoever provided feedback what they mean.

Comment: Thank you. Can the ICC be used to analyse both ordinal as well as continuous outcomes, or is there another measure that is more commonly used to analyse agreement between multiple (>2) raters for continuous scores?

Comment: The ICC (in it's standard form) assumes continous outcomes.